# Can Hadoop be used like Dropbox or Google Drive?

Tags: hadoop, cloud, dropbox, file-storage, cloud-storage

I'm doing some research on Hadoop and cloud storage.
So quite wonder, is Hadoop be able to use like Dropbox or Google Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop vs Dropbox/google driver are not even far relatives of each other. Let me differentiate what each of them is meant for.

**Hadoop**:

A programming framework/ecosystem of frameworks that supports the processing and storage of huge amount of data in a distributed computing environment. HDFS is a framework that falls under this ecosystem which is a distributed file storage system.

**Dropbox and Google Drive**:

These are file storage services that synchronize the files between local storage devices and the cloud. Making it easy to backup, share and access your files from anywhere.

**My conclusion**:
Hadoop can also be used as a cloud storage that acts as backup and access files from anywhere. But it will neither be as user-friendly as dropbox and google drive nor be as efficient as them.

So,

> is Hadoop be able to use like Dropbox or Google Drive
>   Yes, but with zero-user friendly way.

Looking at another perspective, can you use Hadoop **to build** some system similar to dropbox or google drive? 
Yes! and that could be a valid use case for Hadoop.

Comment: do you have any idea where should I start if I going to build this one?

Comment: I am not quite sure about that. But I would suggest you dig deeper into hadoop especially HDFS/HBase, understand it's architecture, configurations, all the other frameworks in the Hadoop's ecosystem.